# Python BeautifulSoup: parsing multiple tables with same table is

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am having to use BeautifulSoup to parse a table, but there are several tables with the same name. See the example below and in this case I want table #6 which has "First goal stats:..."

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLg0b.png)

[page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLg0b.png)

```
site = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(site.content, 'html.parser')
tb = soup.findAll('table',{'id': 'btable'})
table_str = str(tb)
df = pd.read_html(table_str)[0]
```

Comment: Don't provide images of code or data, but provide relevant examples in the question itself. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Do the tables have the same _name_ or the same _id_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tb` is just a list contains all the tables and you can get your table by index.. I think your target table has the index of 4.

```
tb = soup.findAll('table',{'id': 'btable'})
table_str = str(tb[4]) #select only one table by its index
```